# Como verificar de que país é um determinado IP

Tags: php

Bom a minha pergunta é a seguinte:

Eu tenho um arquivo PHP, onde pego o IP do usuário contudo, queria verificar de que país é esse usuário e inserir no banco de dados.

Como poderei verificar de que país é aquele determinado IP?

Obrigado.

Comment: Queria um exemplo concreto, no site do PHP não tenho.

Comment: O exemplo concreto depende de qual solução de base de dados de IP você vai adotar. Quase todas usam requisição normal de HTTP, algumas JSON, e estas requisições tem vários exemplos no site (apesar de não serem especificamente de localização, a lógica é idêntica). Dê uma olhada nas soluções da pergunta indicada, que boa parte delas tem exemplos de como usar nos próprios sites.